# Symfony2 logouts automaticly allt time

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm about to finish project I'm working on for some time now. I want sleep yesterday happy that today will be my last day working on it but Symfony or smth else make a really unpleasant surprise.

For some reason user is getting logout automatically almost always. Sometimes after successful logging in I'm able to make one more request just to get logout on next one.

It had happened few time before that I got logout unexpectedly but it was rare and I connected it with application not being finished yet etc.

I commented out all rules in access_control in security.yml except for ones with role IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY but nothing has changed.

It's happening on all routes and have no idea where to look to fix it.

I created on event listener yesterday but switching it off didn't help either.

Yesterday it worked, today it doesn't. Usually I would review changes I made but none done today yet.

Comment: Does it happen when clearing the cache?

Comment: Is your cache somehow being deleted? If I remember Correctly, FOSUserBundle relies on the same File cache for sessions that normal symfony does.

Comment: Looks like rebooting my PC helped but still have no idea what was happening.

Comment: May be you should take a look at the dev.log and prod.log . It might have some clue

Comment: It may sound silly, can you try closing your browser completely? Some cookies get cleared when the browser is closed.

Comment: I have tried clear cache and different browsers with restarting, nothing helped. But as I wrote after rebooting pc everything works. Would be nice to know what was happening but I guess we will never find out...

Comment: Any solution to this issue guys!